# Proper way to delete ng-repeat item from child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So, I got the following generic structure:

```
<list-item ng-repeat="item in collection">
    <remove-item>
        <a ng-click="remove()">delete</a><!-- this is inside the view.html -->
    </remove-item>
</list-item>
```

I need a proper way to, when triggered, the remove() function remove the full  parent of the clicked .

I got this working calling scope.parent().parent()....remove() on the  directive, but it is a shitty way to do that =P

Is there a better way? (sure there is).

Please, don't mind this lame question. I am new at AngularJs, and I am having a hard time trying to solve that. =(

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, i want to help you but need more explain, you want to call remove action in the directive from controller and return the selected object, right?

Comment: @Maher I need to call remove() for the entire <list-item> directive, clicking on the ng-click inside the <remove-item> directive... the controller on the html, for now, only get the data from my DB and display it on the ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to avoid the `$scope.$parent.$parent ...` problem in Angular. If you are using scopes, you should put any callback or property that you want children to access in a sub-property of the scope. For example, in the parent directive, use `$scope.api.remove = function() {...}` rather than `$scope.remove = function() {...}`. Then you can call it in child directive like so:

```
<list-item ng-repeat="item in collection">
    <remove-item>
        <!-- remove() is bound to $scope.api rather than directly to $scope -->
        <a ng-click="api.remove()">delete</a>
    </remove-item>
</list-item>
```

The other way to do this would be to refactor your code to use controllers rather than scopes. This seems to have become the preferred way of doing things, and it is how Angular 2 works. This pattern is made especially easy by the new [component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) feature in v1.5.0. I won't give a detailed example, but you can read more about this pattern [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html), and more about components [here](https://toddmotto.com/exploring-the-angular-1-5-component-method).